# Pass several columns to an orderBy method via URL

Tags: php, laravel, rest, lumen

I have this code in Lumen 5.6 (Laravel microframework) and I want to have an orderBy method for several columns, for example, http://apisurl/books?orderBy=devices,name,restrictions,category also send asc or desc order.

Lumen's documentation says that we can use the orderBy like this

```
$books = PartnersBooks::all()->orderBy('device', 'asc')->orderBy('restrictions', 'asc')->get();
```

So, I made a function with a foreach to fill an array with different orderBy requests values and tried to put on eloquent queries without succeeding.

Can anybody help me?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $limit = $request->input('limit');

    $books = PartnersBooks::where('is_direct', '=', 1)
      ->with('direct')
      ->whereHas('direct', function ($query) {
          $query->enable()
            ->select(['id', 'book_id', 'name', 'devices', 'flow', 'restrictions', 'countries', 'targeting']);
      })
      ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
      ->paginate($limit, ['id', 'category', 'description']);

     $status = !is_null($books) ? 200 : 204;
     return response()->json($books, $status);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `foreach` that you tried?

Comment: As a side note the `$status = !is_null($books) ? 200 : 204;` line will always return `false`, since `$books` will return an instance of a Paginator, not null. You want `$status = $books->isNotEmpty() ? 200 : 204;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// Get order by input
$orderByInput = $request->input('orderBy');
// If it's not empty explode by ',' to get them in an array, 
// otherwise make an empty array
$orderByParams = !empty($orderByInput) 
    ? explode(',', $orderByInput)
    : [];

$query = PartnersBooks::where('is_direct', '=', 1)
    ->with('direct')
    ->whereHas('direct', function ($query) {
      $query->enable()
        ->select(['id', 'book_id', 'name', 'devices', 'flow', 'restrictions', 'countries', 'targeting']);
    });

// Foreach over the parameters and dynamically add an orderBy
// to the query for each parameter
foreach ($orderByParams as $param) {
    $query = $query->orderBy($param);
}

// End the query and get the results
$result = $query->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: Great @devk how can I manage the asc and/or desc option using this foreach? I started with something like this, but your solution is better for far.

Comment: @FranklinG.Mendoza you can pass it in as the 2nd argument to `->orderBy($param, $order)`.